# I don't have touchpad tap in my mouse properties

Tags: windows-10, mouse, touchpad

my touchpad had been suddenly disabled. I was normally using it and then it just doesn't work anymore. I have tried some solutions that I found online but in most of them I should go to this address:

setting > devices > Mouse > additional mouse options > touchpad

but I am missing the touchpad tap. Is there any way I can fix it?

By the way I have restarted my computer and also tried fn + f10 and I also use windows.

here is the picture:
[image: photo]

Answer (score 0):

seems your computer is not aware of your touchpad

I've a separate hardware device for each of my pointing devices (external mouse, touch pad, touch stick)

[image]

go to device manager and check your touchpad there, look if it's disabled and try to upgrade driver

Comment: my problem is exacly that my touchpad isnt recognized.what you do for that.plus i have only one hardware which is my external mouse

Comment: have you checked in device manager (https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/a-common-and-easy-way-to-access-device-manager-in-windows/)? Is it included there? is the status and driver ok? Have you looked for updated driver?

Comment: I have also checked my device manager. it was messing there too. I am pretty sure it is a software problem cause I haven't damaged my laptop physically.